# Footer moves up when typing

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i've developed a jqm app with phonegap eclipse. when i tap on a textfield and wants type the footer moves up to the buttom of the textfiled i've tapped. what i want to achieve is the footer remains where it is when i tap on any textfiled

```
</div>
  <div id="index_footer3" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#register" data-transition="slide" data-icon="register" data-inline="true" data-role="button">New account</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#fpassword" data-transition="slide"  data-icon="fpassword" data-inline="true" data-role="button">Forgot Password?</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **footer** class and add in **div index_footer3** OR you can also use **index_footer3** id instead of class **footer**

```
$("input").on("focus", function(event){
    if(event.handled !== true)
    {
        $(".ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed").css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        $(".footer").removeClass('out slideup');
        $(".footer").css('display', 'none');
        $(".footer").hide();
    }
    return false;
});

$("input").on("blur", function(event){
   if(event.handled !== true)
   {        
       if(!$("input").is(":focus")){
           $(".ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed").css({ 'position': 'fixed' })
           $(".footer").css('display', 'block');
           $(".footer").show();
       }
   }
   return false;
});
```